# Exploded .obj import

Tags: import

I am new to Blender and tried to open a purchased .obj from TurboSquid. The model opens exploded... am I missing a setting during import to keep everything together? Reference to what the model looks like when imported versus what it is supposed to be are attached. Please help!
Jim
[image]

[image]

Comment: "*am I missing a setting during import*" Yes untick the option *Import Exploded*. Seriously though, this is obviously an inconsistency between different software storing object relations differently. Try to clear parenting with `Alt` + `P` and clearing transforms with `Alt` + `G`

Comment: try to explain which import options you are using, and if you tried different import settings... (eg: split settings?)  this could be easily due to that specific object you purchased, so I guess we can't try to reproduce...